# Can we integrate react component into Aurelia project?

Tags: reactjs, aurelia

I have created one react component and build it using webpack and deployed on server. I want to integrate this component into Aurelia Project.

I tried using below npm module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-react-loader

In above module mentioned, component name need pass into html file. like in example **my-react-component.js** is passing into html file.

But my React Component is loading into root in html tag using below code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    ReactDOM.render((
      <App/>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

and after running webpack module, it is creating one JavaScript file that is called **index_bundle.js** file. Here imported **App** module is main js component. It is rendering into index.html on root element via ReactDOM.

So I am not sure, How I am going to integrate React component link or url into Aurelia application?

Please let me know if you have any doubts in question. I can do explain in detail.

Thanks in advance. 
Harish

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I've built an [aurelia-skeleton](https://github.com/Xceno/aurelia-skeleton-typescript-react-webpack) with typescript and react a while ago. Maybe it's still of use to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, it's really easy to integrate a react component in to an Aurelia app. Check out my project where I do just that here: https://github.com/ashleygrant/aurelia-loves-react

I'm not even using the loader plugin you mentioned.

Here's how to wrap a third-party react component in an Aurelia custom element:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import { noView, bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView(['react-datepicker/react-datepicker.css'])
@inject(Element)
export class DatePicker {
  @bindable selectedDate;
  @bindable onChange;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  selectedDateChanged() {
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={this.selectedDate}
        onChange={date => this.onChange({ date: date })}
      />,
      this.element
    );
  }

  // How to use native DOM events to pass the changed date
  /*render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={this.selectedDate}
        onChange={date => {
          let event = new CustomEvent('change', { 'detail': date });
          // Dispatch the event.
          this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        }
      />,
      this.element
    );
  }*/
}
```

And here's how to do it while using a custom react component that is part of the Aurelia project:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { noView, bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import FormattedDate from '../react-components/formatted-date';

@noView()
@inject(Element)
export class ReactDate {
  @bindable date;
  @bindable format = 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY';

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  dateChanged() {
    this.render();
  }

  formatChanged() {
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <FormattedDate 
        date={this.date}
        format={this.format}
      />,
      this.element
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple. I like doing it by hand rather than using the loader as I can set up databinding for each property so it works in a more "Aurelia-ey" way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking into your project and will try to implement in my project. I will get back to you if will have any questions.

Comment: Hi, In your project I have seen react-date.js file. In that you imported aurelia-framework. It is required to add in React component?

My compoment main file is:

Comment: import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import App from './App';
        export class ReactComponent {
         constructor() {
           this.render();
        }

        render() {
         console.log("called RENDER function")
          ReactDOM.render((
               <App/>
          ), document.getElementById('root'));
        }
     }

And I am integrating into Aurelia like this:
        <template>
           <require from="../react/index_bundle"></require>
           <react-component></react-component>
      </template>

Comment: But I am seeing render function is not calling. Even the log in render function is not coming in log section. 

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't render something that hasn't got a place to be put in the DOM yet. So don't call `render` in the constructor, call it in the `attached` callback.

Comment: Also, why are you using `document.getElementById` in your code? Use Aurelia to get the element passed to you like I do in the example code.

Comment: `document.getElementById`  I am using into React component for loading into root element. You imported `aurelia-framework` into React component. As I understood. Correct? I need to import same way `aurelia-framework` into React component? FYI, In above code, imported `App` component is main React component of my application. Can you tell me what should be code here from React Component side? Current component main file code is below.

Comment: `import React from 'react';` 
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` 
`import App from './App';` 
`export class ReactComponent {
  constructor() { 
        this.render(); 
   } 

   render() { 
      console.log("called RENDER function") 
         ReactDOM.render(( <App/> ), document.getElementById('root')); 
   } 
}`

Comment: I don't think you've looked at the repository of code I posted. I posted an Aurelia app that loads up a couple of React components as custom elements in the Aurelia app. If you just want to render a react component in to a single element with an id of `root` in your page, there's no need to use Aurelia at all. That's just creating a react application.

Comment: But if you want to integrate that react component (called App in your code) in to an Aurelia application as a custom element then you CAN NOT use `document.getElementByid`. What if you want to use the React component in more than one place? That is why I have Aurelia inject the element in to my custom element's view model and pass that element to `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: And finally, I already said that calling ``ReactDOM.render` in the constructor of your Aurelia component is not going to work. The stuff in your custom element's template, such as the `<div id="root"></div>` that I'm assuming is in your custom element's template simply don't exist in the DOM until the `attached` callback happens.

Comment: What is `index_bundle` that is being required in? 

I have no idea what you are doing in your code. Please go look carefully at the repository I posted and see how I am doing this. Again, that code is here: https://github.com/ashleygrant/aurelia-loves-react

I've given you everything you need to do this, but you seemingly have tried to only pay attention to about 25% of the code I posted. You need to look at the entirety of the code, not just small parts.

Comment: I am really impressed by how easy this was to get working. I just followed the examples and everything worked (forgot to call render the first time). I have a custom setup where I am loading everything through plugin-typescript and plugin-babel under JSPM 0.17. I wrote my React component as `.tsx` and the adapter as `.js`. Worked beautifully. Thanks Ashely!